# Android ScrollView inside TableLayout

Tags: android, layout

I see some post with the TableLayout and ScrollView but i put the ScrollView After the first TableRow.
Like this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_orario"
    tools:context="com.ddz.diarioscolastico.setTableActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/giorni"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Lun"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Mar"
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Mer"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Gio"
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_column="6" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Ven"
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_column="7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Sab"
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_column="8" />
    </TableRow>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/ora1"
            android:layout_column="0" />
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m11"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m12"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m13"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m14"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m15"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m16"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="6" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m21"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m22"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m23"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m24"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m25"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m26"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="6" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/ora_3"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m31"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m32"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m33"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m34"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m35"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m36"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="6" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/ora_4"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m41"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m42"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m43"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m44"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m45"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m46"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="6" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/ora_5"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m51"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m52"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m53"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m54"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m55"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m56"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="6" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/ora_6"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m61"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m62"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m63"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m64"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m65"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m66"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="6" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/ora_7"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m71"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m72"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m73"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m74"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m75"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m76"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="6" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/ora_8"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m81"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m82"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m83"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m84"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m85"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_button"
            android:id="@+id/m86"
            android:onClick="addMateria"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="6" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</TableLayout>
```

Android Studio say to me that the app have a Rendering problem NullPointerException.
Why i can't put the ScrollView inside Table?
Is there something wrong in the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITTED CODE**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
tools:context="com.ddz.diarioscolastico.setTableActivity">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/giorni"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Lun"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Mar"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Mer"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_column="5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Gio"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Ven"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_column="7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Sab"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_column="8" />
</TableRow>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/ora1"
                android:layout_column="0" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m11"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m12"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m13"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m14"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m15"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m16"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m21"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m22"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m23"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m24"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m25"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m26"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="3"
                android:id="@+id/ora_3"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m31"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m32"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m33"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m34"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m35"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m36"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="4"
                android:id="@+id/ora_4"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m41"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m42"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m43"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m44"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m45"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m46"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="6" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="5"
                android:id="@+id/ora_5"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m51"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m52"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m53"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m54"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m55"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m56"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="6" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="6"
                android:id="@+id/ora_6"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m61"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m62"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m63"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m64"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m65"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m66"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="6" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="7"
                android:id="@+id/ora_7"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m71"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m72"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m73"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m74"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m75"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m76"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="6" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="8"
                android:id="@+id/ora_8"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m81"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m82"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m83"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m84"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m85"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/new_button"
                android:id="@+id/m86"
                android:onClick="addMateria"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_column="6" />
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: i add the full code. Now i try to put the ScrollView first the TableLayout and all work. But i need to put it after the first row so i have it fixet to the top when user scroll.
But i if put ScrollView and LinearLayout after the first row i have rendering problem and i don't know why.
And the app crash!

Comment: You want a TableLayout inside that a tablerow and a scrollview ryt? and within the scrollview you have tablwrow and texts ryt?

can you please post the entire xml file

Comment: check my editted answer please Click the solve icon if your problem is being solved thank you

Comment: Ok the problem was the fill_parent property to the TableRow.
Your example work because you use `<TableRow
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >`

Comment: i just used your code and the problem was with the background check you color.xml  please click solve if you have got the answer thank you

Comment: instead of color you might have given item in your color.xml

Comment: yes because in my project app i have a color resource and you not.
The problem was fill_parent in the TableRow that Android Studio put automatically when you use the TableRow.

Comment: ok idk i just copied you code just changed the backgroudcolor that's it...anyway hope you got your solution

Comment: Yes i have a resourse that define the color and if you copy only the code xml the resource is miss.
Yes the problem is the fill_parent to the TableRow i don't know why but the rendering don't like ScrollView with inside TableRow that have layout_height and width with fill_parent.
And i see tha in your code that you say "for me work" the TableRow have match_parent and wrap_content property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your ScrollView inside TableRow

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/giorni"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Lun"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Mar"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Mer"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_column="5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Gio"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Ven"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_column="7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Sab"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_column="8" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Mer"
                android:layout_column="5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: I don't think because i need to scroll 8 rows, not only the first.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :scroll working fine after one table row.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
tools:context="com.example.widgetsample.MainActivity">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/giorni"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:text="Lun"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:text="Mar"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:text="Mer"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_column="5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:text="Gio"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:text="Ven"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_column="7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:text="Sab"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_column="8" />
</TableRow>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        />

              <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        />
            <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        />
            <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        />
            <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        /><TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/ora1"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Is not the same that i write?

Comment: You want TableRow in inside the ScrollView right? Now i have edited my code check once @Dario.

Comment: i want ScrollView inside TableRow, after the first row.
I try with the `<ScrollView> <LinearLayout>` but i have a rendering problem